# How to select the column who has this Client name in laravel9

Tags: php, laravel

```
 public function clientname()
    {
        $client = Commande::Where('client_name' , '=' , '')->get();
        return response()->json($client);
    };
```

I want to select the column who has this Client name, but doesn't work -- they give an empty array instead.

Comment: your question is not clear can you explain a little bit

Comment: i want select who have the same name

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Firstly there is no need of using an '=' as it  will automatically check, and also if you want to check if first value match the other one , it will use '==' not '=' as = is use to assign the values
Secondly, For your answer try using this

```
public function clientname()
    {
        $client = Commande::where('client_name', '')->get();
        return response()->json($client);
    };
```

Comment: this will definitely show syntax error. his code syntax is correct

Comment: sorry, I forgot to remove an extra comma.

Comment: that return an empty array

Comment: did you replaced the empty inverted commas with the desired name?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the clients which has same name, you can use the query below. You will than client's name and how many times it repeated.

```
$clients = Client::select('client_name',\DB::raw('COUNT(client_name)'))
->groupBy('client_name')
->having(\DB::raw('COUNT(client_name)'),'>' ,1)
->get();
```

Answer (score -1):

Laravel whereColumn method is used to verify that two columns are equal. if you use regular where function it will compare first parameter as column and second parameter as value but whereColumn function takes both parameter as column name so use this function.
[Check Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries)

```
 public function clientname()
 {
    $client = Commande::whereColumn('client_name' , 'client_name')->get();
    return response()->json($client);
 };
```

Comment: that give me all data in table

Comment: this should work laravel has a whereColumn function to compare Columns

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).